# How to rearrange blocks in a UML state diagram

Tags: uml, plantuml, state-diagram

I just created a state diagram and right now I am struggling with the positions of the blocks. My goal is to have States 1,2,4,5 in a "down"-row and state 3 at the right from state 1.

See my UML code and the attached screenshot for the current (left) and wanted (right) design

**UML Code:**

```
@startuml diagramStackO
scale 400 width
[*]    -down->  State1
State1 -down->  State2
State1 -right-> State3
State2 -up->    State3
State2 -down->  State4
State4 -->      State5
State5 -->      [*]
@enduml
```

**Screenshot (left: current right: what it should look like)**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) The base functions are easy to use and changes are quickly implemented. "Hope is the last to die" !

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My first advice would be to just ignore it and move on... Tweaking diagrams in PlantUML to get them "just right", even for little things, can take up a lot of time.

However, as someone who spends way too much time in getting their diagrams just right, there are two things that come to mind.

### Using `ortho`

The first one is to just add `skinparam linetype ortho`. This is the least work but also gives the least improvment:

[image]

```
@startuml
skinparam linetype ortho

[*]    -down->  State1
State1 -down->  State2
State1 -right-> State3
State2 -up->    State3
State2 -down->  State4
State4 -->      State5
State5 -->      [*]
@enduml
```

### Using a hidden container

The other is adding a hidden container which a *bit* more work, but not *too much*, I think.

To get the vertical alignment that you want, the states need to be grouped together:

[image]

All we need to do now is hide the container:

[image]

The code I used to achieve this effect is:

```
@startuml
skinparam {
    shadowing false

    state {
        BackgroundColor<<HIDDEN>> hidden
        BorderColor<<HIDDEN>> hidden
    }
}


state " " as _ <<HIDDEN>> {
    state State1
    state State2
    state State4
    state State5
}


[*]    -down->  State1
State1 -down->  State2
State1 -right-> State3
State2 -right->    State3
State2 -down->  State4
State4 -->      State5
State5 -->      [*]
@enduml
```

Comment: great answer, I did not catch that way to do looking at PlantUML

Comment: @bruno Well, I have the advantage of having used Graphviz _a lot_ before switching to PlantUML. As PlantUMl use the Grahpviz layour engine, a lot of my previous knowledge comes in useful for edgecases like these. :-)

Comment: brilliant! what a mastery of this tool!